# How to gracefully handle "Key not found" In a Scala map?

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

In summary, I need a functional way to **do one thing** if a value was found in a Map and **Do another thing** if it was not found. **Note that I am NOT interested in the value returned but the action done.**

Read on for the details.

I have a map of service name (friendly) to a part of a URL PATH (not easy to remember). 
Here is the initialization.

```
val serviceMap = Map("read" -> "cryptic-read-path",
  "save" -> "cryptic-save-path", "county" -> "cryptic-zip-code-to-county-service.");
```

All the alternatives I am aware of lead to an if statement with a loaded `then` part, but a simple, `404` `else` part.
Here are some that I thought about

```
if (serviceMap.contains(service)) {
    //Do stuff
} else {
    //Issue a 404
}
```

It's equivalent with predicate reversed

```
if (!serviceMap.contains(key)) //issue a 404
//Do stuff
```

Both approaches above require me to check-then-get.

Another one (discouraged by [Option documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) )

```
  serviceMap.get(service) match {
  case _ : Option[String]=> //Do stuff
  case _  => //issue 404
}
```

Yet a third one

```
  serviceMap.get(service).forEach {//Dostuff and return, since it's just one element }
  //issue 404 if you are here.
```

Per [Option documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option), I am encouraged to treat `Option` as a  collection, so the last alternative seems better, but the use of `forEach` seems odd to change execution flow after the loop.

It is my inexperience, but all of these look too verbose and inappropriate to me. Can you guys give me a better option or comment on the approaches? 
Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: I am new to stack-exchange. It's really moving to see such support from total strangers!

Comment: Your question is good as it shows research effort and what you tried. Good questions get good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of options that are clearer:

1. `match` with `unapply` (which avoids the type-erasure problems of `_ : Option[CantTellWhatThisIsAtRuntime]`):

   ```
   serviceMap.get(service) match {
     case Some(path) => // Do stuff and return
     case _ => // 404
   }
   ```
2. Use a `fold` to extract the value (this assumes that you can type your 404 appropriately):

   ```
   serviceMap.get(service).fold(/* 404 */) { path =>
     // Do stuff and return
   }
   ```
3. Use `map` + `getOrElse` to transform the path into a response or return / throw a 404 ([hat tip to Mikesname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32361039/135978)):

   ```
   serviceMap.get(service).map { path =>
     // Do stuff and return
   } getOrElse {
     // 404
   }
   ```
4. Use `Map`'s `getOrElse` method (assumes you throw your 404):

   ```
   val path = serviceMap.getOrElse(service, throw Error404)
   // Do stuff and return
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't the `z` part in fold (/* 404 */) will always be executed?

Comment: Nope - it's not executed unless the `Option` is `None` (it's a by-name `=> T` not a by-reference `T`).  You can try it yourself in the REPL: `(None: Option[String]).fold({println("Runs"); "Ha"})(_ + "Hi")` vs. `Option("Hi").fold({println("Does not run"); "Ha"})(_ + "Hi")`

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand!

Comment: For me the last option works (#4) best cause I need to throw an exception on 404.

Answer (score 4):

I would think the idiomatic way is to use `map` and `getOrElse`:

```
val result = serviceMap.get(service).map { url =>
  // do something with url
} getOrElse {
  // not found
}
```

In general, don't think about `Option` as a one-element collection to *loop over* (which isn't the functional approach) but to *transform* into something else.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would do it using pattern matching. It makes it very readable.

```
serviceMap.get(service) match {
  case Some(s) => println("Here's my string from the map! " + s)
  case _ => //issue 404
}
```

Also, code can be easily modified then. For instance, if at some point in the future you'll need to do stuff if specifically for the value that map to "cryptic-read-path", you can do this:

```
serviceMap.get(service) match {
  case Some("cryptic-read-path") => //do stuff that is specific for cryptic read path
  case Some(s) => println("Here's my string from the map! " + s)
  case _ => //issue 404
}
```

For the third option, you propose returning inside a foreach. That would cause a non-local return, which is not efficient. 
Read more about it [here](https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#return-statements)

Edit:
You also can do this if you don't need the result of the get call:

```
serviceMap.get(service) match {
  case Some(_) => //do stuff
  case _ => //issue 404
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the for/each non-local return was bothersome to me from the start, but thanks for shedding more light on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is perform different actions based on the value existing or not. While pattern matching is a less-idiomatic way to convert an `Option` to a value, I would say it is wholly appropriate as a branching mechanism to choose between multiple actions. For that reason I would recommend using the `match` alternative you proposed.

If, however, you disagree that it is appropriate, consider looking at your problem as one of converting an `Option` into an action:

```
 val response = serviceMap.get(service).map { value =>
   // do stuff to convert into a 200 response
 }.getOrElse {
   // create 404 response
 }
```

The `map` converts the any `Some[String]` into a `Some[Response]`, while keeping keeping a `None`. Now that you have an `Option[Response]` you can use `getOrElse` to substitute your 404 response for the possibility of a `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Lift the `Map` to a partial function defined only for mapped keys, namely for instance, for a given map

```
val a = Map( 1->2, 3->4)
```

we can lift `a` with

```
a.lift
Int => Option[Int] = <function1>
```

and so

```
a.lift(1)
Option[Int] = Some(2)

a.lift(0)
Option[Int] = None
```

Consider then a for comprehension for instance like this,

```
val ok = for { v <- a.lift(1); res <- Some(awesome_stuff(v)) }
         yield res

ok getOrElse report404
```

If `v` or `res` do not succeed (namely, that are `None`), then `ok` is `None`.